# How to keep the launch screen up in ios 9?

Tags: ios, ios9, launch-screen

I have an ios 9 app that I am building. How do I make the launch screen appear everytime the app starts?

Comment: Why do you want to? Nobody wants to be forced to stare at a launch screen.

Comment: one way i can think of is using the appdelagate and creating a similar toyour launch screen view and force it to show up when you restart the app from background lets say. But yeah like rob said why would someone do that? What's your intentions?

Comment: What you are trying to do is really bad UX and I strongly advise you not to do it. What you want to achieve can probably be solved in a different, more user friendly way.

Comment: Don't do this but perhaps you want the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key set to `YES` in your Info.plist. Again, don't do this.